# Track if two functions have been executed

Tags: javascript

I have two functions. `funcA` and `funcB`. I want to track when both of them have been executed.

So I have this code:

```js
let addExecuted = 0;
function bothFunctionsExecuted(){
  addExecuted++

  if(addExecuted === 2){
  // Both functions executed so console log it
  addExecuted = 0; // set this to initial state
  console.log('Both functions executed...');
  }
  
};
```

Then I can execute `bothFunctionsExecuted()` inside each of my functions. but honestly this is not the good solution because if one of the functions execute twice I can still see `console.log('Both functions executed...');`

I want to see the console log only if both of the functions have been executed.

Comment: why do you need to track if both functions have executed?

Comment: I have two animations that occur at different times with different durations... I want to track when both of them have been finished...

Comment: You can do it with Promisses (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: @ radulle I know what promises are but I have no idea how to do it this way...

Comment: Maybe look at promises. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and also things like Promise.all [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand the problem. If you know the start time and duration of the animations, you can find out which one will end last, and just use the function which fires when that animation ends to determine that both animations have finished.

Answer (score 0):

Use Promises, here is an example of how you can use promises (your functions have to have to run `resolve()` at the end):

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

With Promise.all you are saying to JS continue only when all of the Promises (in your case functions) have resolved.

You can find more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)